# Image selection in gridster jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridster

On my website I use gridster widgets.Widgets have images on them which are retrieved from a remote location. I wish that user should also be able to add the images on widgets. When user clicks on the add image button a dialog box with set of images should appear. How can this be done?

```js
var gridster;


gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
    widget_base_dimensions: [100, 100],
    widget_margins: [5, 5],
    helper: 'clone',
    serialize_params: function($w, wgd) {
        return {
            images: $w.find('textarea').val().trim(),
            col: wgd.col,
            row: wgd.row,
            size_x: wgd.size_x,
            size_y: wgd.size_y
        }
    },
    resize: {
        enabled: true
    }
}).data('gridster');


var json = [{
        "html": "https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/802768-200.png,https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/802768-200.png,https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/802768-200.png", //3 Images
        "col": 1,
        "row": 1,
        "size_y": 2,
        "size_x": 2
    }, {
        "html": "https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/802768-200.png,https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/802768-200.png", // 2 Images
        "col": 4,
        "row": 1,
        "size_y": 2,
        "size_x": 2
    },

    {
        "html": "https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/802768-200.png", // 1 Image
        "col": 6,
        "row": 1,
        "size_y": 2,
        "size_x": 2
    }

];




for (var index = 0; index < json.length; index++) {
    var images = json[index].html.split(',');
    var imageOutput = "";

    for (var j = 0; j < images.length; j++) {
        imageOutput += '<div class="imagewrap"><img src=' + images[j] + '> <input type="button" class="removediv" value="X" /></div></div>';
    }

    gridster.add_widget('<li class="new" ><button class="delete-widget-button" style="float: right;">-</button>' + imageOutput + '<textarea>' + json[index].html + '</textarea></li>', json[index].size_x, json[index].size_y, json[index].col, json[index].row);
}




$('.removediv').on('click', function() {
    var textArea = $(this).parent().next();
    var text = textArea.val();
    var imgSrc = $(this).prev().attr("src");
    textArea.val(text.replace(imgSrc, ""));
    $(this).closest('div.imagewrap').remove();
    serialize();
});


$(document).on("click", ".delete-widget-button", function() {
  var gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster().data('gridster');
    gridster.remove_widget($(this).parent());
});


$('.js-seralize').on('click', function() {
    serialize();
});

function serialize(){
var s = gridster.serialize();
    $('.gridster ul li').each((idx, el) => { // grab the grid elements
        s[idx].html = $('textarea', el).html(); // add the html key/values

        json_variable = JSON.stringify(s)
    });
    $('#log').val(json_variable);
}



//I want to display multiple images on new json into the widgets along with delete image button on each image
```

```css
textarea {
  resize: none;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 80%;
}
.imagewrap {display:inline-block;position:relative;}
.removediv {position:absolute;right:1%;top:1%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.gridster/0.5.6/jquery.gridster.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/demos/assets/css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.gridster/0.5.6/jquery.gridster.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="gridster">
    <ul>
    
    </ul>
        
</div>
<button class="js-seralize btn btn-success mr-2">Serialize</button>
<textarea id="log"></textarea>
```

Comment: My Fiddle so far   https://jsfiddle.net/xfzkak2z/

Comment: Please don't post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time and then your question makes no sense to anyone. Include your code, right in your question in a "code snippet".

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yeah Sure :)